# beeline cant connect passing a init script from hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hive, beeline

It's possible initialize the connection with Hive passing a init script from HDFS?

I tried `beeline -u <<url>> -i wasb://<path-to-init-script>`, the connection is estabelished but the script initiliazation fails with 'no such file or directory', but the files exists and is listed with `hdfs dfs -ls <<path-to-file>>` and ẁith `hdfs dfs -ls wasb://<path-to-file>>` too. The same happens if i try with `beeline -u <<url>> -f wasb://<path-to-file>`.

I am running inside a HDInsight(HDI 3.5) connected by ssh and the connection with the Hive is running in `http mode`. The Hadoop version is the 2.7.